# Getting Specific Data From the Following JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

## **Problem**

I am trying to get a specific item from the following JSON, but I am not sure how I can do it. For example, I am just trying to retrieve all the objects with the ID "mondaymenu" in the array "collection1":

## **Code**

```
Object {name: "FF_1_menuitems", count: 223, frequency: "weekly", version: 7, newdata:   true…}
count: 223
frequency: "weekly"
lastrunstatus: "success"
lastsuccess: "Fri Mar 28 2014 14:00:21 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
name: "FF_1_menuitems"
newdata: true
nextrun: "Fri Apr 04 2014 14:00:21 GMT+0000 (UTC)"

results: Object
collection1: Array[33]
   0: Object
      mondaymenu: "Bacon"
      __proto__: Object
   1: Object
      mondaymenu: "Belgian Waffles"
      __proto__: Object
```

I've tried Googling around, but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly do you want here? Do you need to know how to use JSON, access an array, or both?  Can you post the original json object and/or array?

Comment: Both would be helpful!

The original json is:
http://pastebin.com/Pam7L16T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a json object `json_data`, then you could access the data in it by using

```
json_data.somekey
```

or

```
json_data['somekey']
```

In your specific example, (assuming you've assigned json_data) you can access `collection1` by using

```
json_data.results.collection1 // or json_data['results']['collection1']
```

To find all objects with ID "mondaymenu" in `collection1` you would do something like

```
// loop through collection1
for (i = 0; i < json_data.results.collection1.length; i++) {
  // if 'mondaymenu' isn't there, this will be null (false)
  if (json_data.results.collection1[i]['mondaymenu']) {

    // do something here

  }
}
```

Comment: My JSON is stored in the variable "data" and when I run your suggestion above (where "json_data" is replaced with "data"), I get returnd "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" in the console even though it console.log's the "data" JSON correctly.

Here is the code:

function kimonoCallback(data) {
    console.log(data);
    for (i = 0; i <data.results.collection1.length; i++) {
        if (data.results.collection1[i]['mondaymenu']) {

            console.log(data.results.collection[i]['mondaymenu']);

        }
    }
}

Comment: You are using `data.results.collection[i]['mondaymenu']` instead of `data.results.collection1[i]['mondaymenu']`.  You may need to use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) if your data is actually coming in as a string.